# Adjacent Bar Charts in MatplotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to show multiple matplotlib plots at once?
i.e. call plt.show() twice, and have it show two different windows with two different graphs at the same time?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Me and my partner looked through the matplotlib examples but we are Python novices doing it for a research project, tried using plt.subplot() but we couldn't figure it out

Comment: There is for example [the subplots demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) on the matplotlib page. Apart this question is not useful because there is no way of knowing at which point any problem occurs.